# Is Hoffmann & Kunze Outdated?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I was looking for books in linear algebra and I came across a Math Stack exchange post explaining why the Linear Algebra book by Hoffman & Kunze is outdated. Is the book outdated or can it be considered an exaggeration ? Is Friedberg, Insel, and Spence equally or more rigorous and modern ? I was not able to find that post again and hence I am asking this as a separate question.

I am an undergrad and I have completed a course in Linear Algebra using Strang's Introduction to linear algebra and I was looking for a book on linear algebra that would be considered proof based and rigorous up to to the level of a strong undergrad. I want the book to possibly cover linear algebra in infinite dimensional fields and also over the complex field also (I guess quaternion and all would be there in M. Artin's book) I will be doing Abstract Algebra using M. Artin's Algebra book and Benedict Gross' lectures and I want to be done with Linear Algebra or at least until I take courses in Functional Analysis etc. I'm not using Sheldon Axler's book because it is less rigorous then Hoffman, doesnt include content on actualy finding the Jordan Form etc and it doesn't cover the complex field. I have also considered Halmos' book but that is even older and the title says Finite Dimensional and I would prefer one with infinite dimensions.

Any advice is appreciated

Edit: Changed sentence structure

Comment: Can you give a link to the discussion of why H&K is outdated?

Comment: @angryavian  I'm not able to find it like i mentioned. I remember it saying that Greek vector forms are used and some theory or rather the approach to some of the theory is outdated

Comment: Friedberg Insel and Spence is the book I studied from and I liked it very much for the most part (I just didn't like their chapter 7 on Jordan Canonical forms, and I didn't like Chapter 4 on determinants). I don't think Hoffman and Kunze can be considered outdated... honestly linear algebra is such a basic and well-established subject that as long as you pick one decent textbook and follow it carefully atleast 80-90% faithfully you can't go wrong at all. Doesn't matter if its Friedberg/Hoffman/Axler (in fact I even learnt linear algebra from Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced calculus book).

Comment: The statement above that Linear Algebra Done Right "doesn't cover the complex field" is way wrong. The first section of the book begins with three pages introducing the complex field, which plays a huge role throughout the book. Also, the statement that Linear Algebra Done Right "is less rigorous than Hoffman" makes no sense to me. Both books present rigorous proofs throughout.

Comment: You say you'll be reading *Algebra*by Artin. That's great! It also means it will cover the linear algebra you need from scratch. There's one thing I think is important before studying linear algebra in any book, and that's to have at least a modest acquaintance with vector geometry. For example, *Elementary Vector Geometry* by Schuster is enough, but there are others that go more in depth too.